# Statements out of function, but where?

Tags: c++11, for-loop, if-statement

Trying to get my last assignment in for the quarter, balance my job, and my other class. I would love an extra set of eyes to tell me where in the world my statements go out outside of my function:

This is an implementation file. The associated header is throwing no errors.

I get the following errors:

1.) In the file included from tests.cpp:7:0:
GBoard.cpp:31:2: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘for’

```
for (int r=0; r<15; r++)
```

2.) GBoard.cpp:31:14: error: ‘r’ does not name a type

```
for (int r=0; r<15; r++)
```

But I am pretty sure 2 is part of my code being outside of the function somehow.

Here is my code, parts redacted so I don't get hit w/ plagiarism:

```
bool Gfunction::makeMove(int redacted,int redacted,char secret)
{

    if(redacted >= 0 && redacted < 15 && redacted >= 0 && redacted<15)
    {
        if(redacted() == UNFINISHED && function[redacted][redacted] == '.')
        function[redacted][redacted] = secret;
        return true;
    }   
        else
    {
        return false;

    }

    int track = 0;


    for(int r=0;r<15;r++)
    {
        track = 0;
            for(int c=0;c<15;c++)
            {
                    if(function[r][c] == secret)
                    {
                track++;
                    if(track==5)
                        {
                                if(secret == 'x')
                                secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
                                else
                            secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
                                return true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    track = 0;
                }
        }

    }   



    for(int r=0;r<15;r++)
    {
            track = 0;
            for(int c=0;c<15;c++)
            {
                    if(function[r][c] == secret)
                    {  
                        track++;
                        if(track==5)
                        {
                            if(secret == 'x')
                                secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
                                else
                                secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
                                return true;
                        }

                    }
                        else
                    {
                            track = 0;
                    }
            }

    }



        int r = 0, c = 0;
        for(int redacted = 0; redacted<15; redacted++)
        {
            r = redacted;
                c = 0;
                track = 0;
                while(r < 15 && c < 15)
                {
                    if(function[r][c] == secret)
                    {
                        track++;
                        if(track == 5)
                        {
                                if(secret == 'x')
                                secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
                                else
                                secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
                                return true;
                        }
                }
                        else
                        {
                                track = 0;
                        }
                                r++;
                                c++;
        }
    }

    for(int redacted = 0; redacted<15; redacted++)
    {
            r=0;
            c=redacted;
            track=0;
            while(r<15 && c<15)
                {
                    if(function[r][c] == secret)
                    {
                            track++;
                            if(track == 5)
                            {
                                if(secret == 'x')
                                secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
                                else
                                secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
                                return true;
                        }
            }
                        else
                        {
                                track = 0; 
                        }
                                r++;
                                c++;
                }
        }


    for(int redacted=0; redacted<15; redacted++)
    {
        r=redacted;
        c=15-1;
        track=0;
        while(r<15 && c>=0)
        {
                    if(function[r][c] == secret)
                    {
                        track++;
                        if(track == 5)
                {
                    if(secret == 'x')
                            secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
                            else
                            secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
                            return true;
                        }
            }
                            else
                    {
                            track = 0;
                    }
                            r++;
                            c--;
        }
    }


    for(int redacted=15-1;redacted>=0;redacted--)
    {
            r=0;
            c=redacted;
            track=0;
            while(r<15 && c>= 0)
            {
                    if(function[r][c] == secret)
                    {
                        track++;
                        if(track == 5)                    
                        {
                                if(secret == 'x')
                                secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
                                else
                                secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
                                return true;
                        }
            }
                        else
                        {
                            track = 0;
                        }
                            r++;
                            c--;
            }
        } 


    for(int r=0;r<15;r++)
    {
            for(int c=0;c<15;c++)
            {
            if(function[r][c] == '.')
                {
                    secret squirrel stuff = UNFINISHED;
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }  
        secret squirrel stuff = DRAW;
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Your indentation of the code is irregular and inconsistent. Please try to fix the indentation and the problem probably turns out to be a closing `}` to much somewhere (which is really hard to check currently).

Comment: And that folks is why we should structure code both logically and even physically. Btw my bet is something happened between line 76-101. I suspect unbalanced braces within this `for`

Comment: I had to remove some of my comments/guides so the code would display properly in the comment/so I wouldn't get hit w/ plagiarism. Thank you for the guidance. I have already looked for closing } but was unable to find where it would be missing.

Comment: By the way, most of the code you show will never run anyway, since you *always* return from the function inside the first `if else`.

Comment: And it could be that some of the redactions contains the problem, which of course makes it even harder for us. And this is also a good example of why you should never write large chunks of code without testing. Write a little bit, build, test. Write the next little bit, build test. And so on... That way it will be very easy to know when and where a problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your innermost `if` statements. For example:

```
if(track == 5)
{
    if(secret == 'x')
        secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
        else
        secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
        return true;
}
```

could be

```
if(track == 5)
{
    if(secret == 'x')
        secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
    else
        secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
    return true;
}
```

or

```
if(track == 5)
{
    if(secret == 'x')
        secret squirrel stuff = X_WON;
     else{
        secret squirrel stuff = O_WON;
        return true;
     }
}
```

depending on you algorithm logic.